# Split Lines between Two Points

Tags: python, python-re

I have a file that has some random words at the start and end on different amounts of lines each time. I am trying to only read the lines between the first point *** START OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE *** and the second point *** END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***. How would I go about writing this? Am I meant to use re.search and if so how would I go about doing that for a file?

Comment: So the file has some random text and then I just want to use the data between the points *** START OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE *** and *** END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE *** and then there is more random text at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following logic:

```py
inp = """START OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE
line 1
line 2
line 3
END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE"""

content = re.search(r'\bSTART OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE\b\s*(.*?)\s*END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE\b', inp, flags=re.S)
print(content.group(1))
```

This prints:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are good when the file will fit into memory. In cases where it doesn't, the usual idiom (in any language) is to create a new file containing only the lines of interest. In Python, assuming that your input file is "input.txt" and your output is "output.txt", it would look like this:

```py
with open('input.txt') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        if line[:-1] == '*** START OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***':
            break
    for line in f_in:
        if line[:-1] == '*** END OF SYNTHETIC TEST CASE ***':
            break
        f_out.write(line)
```

Some things to note in the above:

1. The `with` statement ensures that both files will be closed once outside of the logic.  This will be particularly important for `f_out`, since its buffer may need to be flushed to disk.
2. The line as read will have `\n` on the end, so the test for your sentinel strings uses `line[:-1]`, clipping the final character from the line. You could also use `line.strip()`, if you wanted to remove all whitespace from both ends.

Comment: For this one, it works if there is only one line of text in between the start and end but what about if there were a bunch, how would you do that?

Comment: If you try it, you'll see that it works for any number of lines between the start and end: the second `for` loop writes all the lines *until* the end marker. Or are you asking how you'd find multiple instances of start/end pairs?